# imagemagick convert +append multipul files without using the *

Tags: imagemagick

I can not use the * wildcard, but I want to append multiple files into one output file. If there is a variation of the following line that will work I can't find it.

```
convert -append /home/file1.png /home/file2.png /user/file3.png /test/output.png
```

Thanks in advance.

- waits for the traditional question down voting. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
montage balloon.gif medical.gif present.gif shading.gif \ -mode Concatenate  -tile x1  montage_cat.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [brace expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace)

```
convert -append /home/file[123].png /test/output.png
```

or

```
convert -append /home/file_{1..3}.png /test/output.png
```

Comment: That would work if the files were file_1.jpg file_2.jpg but I'm not sure how it would work for /dir1/file1.jpg /dir2/letters.jpg

Comment: Brace expressions can expand letters, words, and support both groups & nesting. Try `echo /dir{1..3}/{green,gr{a,e}y{1..5}}.png`